# Tracking click conversions with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, click-tracking

Is there anyway I can use Google Analytics to track click conversions on a link?

For example, if I have a link to `www.a.com` , is it possible for google to track the number of times that particular link was shown on my page and then track how many times it was really clicked? **The problem is** that I do not show the link to www.a.com every time the page loads. I am using a random function (server side) to generate a different link everytime. I would like Google Analytics to provide me with the click conversion for each of the links I choose to show the user.

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can track just about anything using Google Analytics' [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) - here's how you might do it for the two cases of (a) showing a link and (b) a user clicking the link:

(a) Track showing the link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Shown', 'http://www.a.com/']);
</script>
```

(b) Track user clicking the link

```
<a href="http://www.a.com/" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Clicked', 'http://www.a.com/']); return true;">...</a>
```

Of course, given that you probably *don't* want to hard-code for both of these Javascript events, you can use a handy Javascript function to do all the work for you when links have a specific class - I like to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), so here's a quick example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
  ... assuming jQuery has been loaded and you're using the
      standard Google Analytics Asynchronous tracking snippet

      URL: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('a.tracked').length ) {
        $('a.tracked').each(function() {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Shown', $(this).attr('href')]);
            $(this).bind( 'click', function() {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Clicked', $(this).attr('href')]);
                return true;
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

... and then every link with `class="tracked"` should be tracked accordingly.

---

**Update:** New code, but sure - you could even specify which group a link belongs to and track the group instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ( $('a.tracked').length ) {
            $('a.tracked').each(function() {
                var groupRegExp =/group([a-zA-Z])/i;
                var group = groupRegExp.exec( $(this).attr('class') );
                if (
                    ( !group ) ||
                    ( !group.length )
                ) {
                    var group = "groupUnknown";
                } else {
                    var group = group[0];
                }
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Shown', group]);
                $(this).bind( 'click', function() {
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Clicked', group]);
                    return true;
                });
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

... which should work for `class="tracked groupA"`, `class="groupA tracked"`, etc.

---

**Update x2:**

... and to account for the behavior which yc01 mentioned, a slight modification to the function bound to tracked anchor tags:

```
                $(this).bind( 'click', function() {
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', 'Clicked', group]);
                    setTimeout('document.location = "' + $(this).attr('href') + '"', 100)
                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: First of all, great answer! Could not ask for much more :)  I just have one more question, does the value of the last parameter, where you inserted the URL of the link (e.g. $(this).value('href')) must be a URL or can it also be a String? Since I have 2 groups of links I would like to treat all links from Group A as one entity... therefore I would like to create something like  _gap.push(...'Shown', 'Group A') and _gap.push(...'Shown', Group B'). Is that valid?

Comment: @Joel - I was using URL's for exact tracking, but the linked Event Tracking document details what Google expects to see (probably some limits on string length) - updated w/a code sample which uses the link's class to determine which group it belongs to :)

Comment: Thank you for very much, been a while since I've received such a good answer!

Comment: This code will only work reliably for links that open in new windows. Otherwise, there will be a race condition, and it won't track fully.

Comment: @danlefree that's not the race condition I'm referring to. Yes, that one exists, but its mostly trivial. The more serious one is that browsers do not consistently fully execute onclick handlers if they take too long before the page unloads. That's why you see a lot of implementations with setTimeout code.

Comment: @danlefree see this Google Analytics Help Article for a primer: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527 . I encounter this race condition a lot, and trust me, not using some sort of setTimeout, or not replacing on click with onmousedown, results in some serious undercounting.

Comment: @yc01 - I was looking at ways to detect whether `_gaq` was actively pushing data or just queueing, but I've added a code sample based upon the Google Analytics doc you linked which *should* account for the condition.

Comment: @danlefree good edit. Removed my down-vote.